# Laravel load read and unread messages for chat application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am developing a chat application using `Laravel and Vue`.

When the chat opens, page scrolls down to the bottom of the page with latest 50 messages.

I have a model `message` and `message_notifications` and `message_notifications` has 1 row for each user in the group and `is_seen` flag. That is how I can get unread message by user.

`Messages` table has following fields

```
id| body | conversation_id | user_id
```

`MessageNotification` table has following fields

```
id | message_id | conversation_id | user_id | is_seen
```

I have implemented the infinite top loading using the `paginator`. So when user reaches to the top of the scroll `limit 25 offset 0` becomes `limit 25 offset 25` and so on.

Now I am trying to implement any common chat application feature, when user opens a chat group conversation, load all unread messages and load last n number of message before the unread message.

So I have a method to `getMessages` which return paginator collection ignoring the `is_seen` flag.

```
select `message_notification`.`id` as `notification_id`,
       `messages`.*
from `messages`
    inner join `message_notification`
        on `message_notification`.`message_id` = `messages`.`id`
where `messages`.`conversation_id` = 406
  and `message_notification`.`user_id` = 4
  order by mc_messages.id desc
  limit 25 offset 0
```

Now how can I load all the unread messages in a conversation along with 25 of the latest read messages?

I tried to merge 2 collection but one of the collection will be with pagination and the other without so it doesnt work properly.

If I send 2 collection to the `vue` and merge it on the `vue` end, pagination becomes useless as I will mark all unread messages as read on `mounted` so next time the query is fired, `limit 25 offset 25` will give some of the same data.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @MikeRoss are you using relationships. If you implement these you can use Laravel model funcitons like 
    Messages::whereIsSeen(true)->limit(20);

Comment: @WouterVeen my problem is not to mark them as read. It's merging unread messages with read messages and infinite top scroll loading.

Comment: I would get 25 read messages as one collection then in another query i would get unread messages then merge the collection as in laravel documentation OR I would give them as 2 args to vue rather than 1, it might even give you more control, is it possible for you to do something like this?

Comment: @amirkamizi yes, I tried that, problem with that is pagination. When user opens the chat all unread messages are marked as read so the result set changes when scrolling to top and loading next set of 25 messages.

Comment: @MikeRoss oh I understand, then I see that in your query you've ordered by message.id. but in my opinion you should add another column to your db "updated_at" so when you get read msg order them by updated_at rather than id. when a is_seen status is changed the updated_at would change as well.for pagination because you don't want those unread message to be load twice, you can A:change the unread to read and reload the data in background (all of it as read now) OR B:send a count of recently changed read messages to backend so it would offset + count and updated_at order. what do you think?

Comment: Ended up using cursor paginator which is basically same as you suggested, pagination using `id` and `created_at`